# Over Configuration Syndrome

Tags: java

Came over a concept called "Over Configuration Syndrome", this simply means that you put everything you possibly can into config files.

Is this considered a wrong approach? When is too much?

I have found that by fully leveraging config files makes the code more extensible and more easy to maintain.

Comment: if you find you can hardly write any code without an associated configuration file, possibly wrapped by a complex hierarchy of implementations of the `Configuration` interface, you probably suffer from this syndrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this considered a wrong approach?

Considered by whom?

Obviously the people who invented the label "Over-configuration Syndrome" thought it was the wrong approach.

But clearly, doing anything "too much" is a bad idea, assuming that people can agree on how much is too much.

> When is too much?

Yes.  That is the real issue here!

Configurability is a trade-off:

- If your application is not configurable enough, then you will run into problems trying to use it in different contexts to the one it was originally implemented for.  You may fail altogether, or you may find that you have to modify the application to make it work.
- Too much configurability tends to make your application more complicated to write, and more difficult to test.  (How do the different configuration parameters interact?)  It can also make the application more complicated to use.

You need to strike a balance between too little and too much configurability.  But I don't think there is an objective answer to "How much is too much" ...

Answer (score 3):

You only have to specify the unconventional aspects of the project. Overdoing it puts lots of 'usual' things in the same place as atypical ones.. hence you cannot identify them anymore.

Think about what you would like to get from the config files. And what would help you more.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration